# Using Screen Sharing app, all remote Mac screens appear pixellated

Tags: remote-desktop, screen-sharing

I've got a couple of Macs that I regularly screen share to using the build-in Screen Sharing app:

[image]

A month or two ago, both started looking very pixellated when viewed — text is very difficult to read.

Here's an example:

[image]

My first thought was that this was related to Screen Sharing's scaling or quality settings, but I've tried all combinations of both to no avail.

I shrugged it off as a broken update or something, and didn't think anything of it.

Until I screen shared from a *different* Mac, and both of the remote Macs looked great again:

[image]

The problem source Mac specs:

```
macOS Sierra 10.12.2 (16C67)
MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Early 2013)
NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M 1024 MB
Intel HD Graphics 4000 1536 MB
Screen Sharing v1.7.1 (494.15)
```

The working source Mac specs:

```
macOS Sierra 10.12.2 (16C67)
Mac mini (Mid 2011)
Intel HD Graphics 3000
Screen Sharing v1.7.1 (494.15)
```

Any idea what's going on here? How do I make screen sharing great again?

Comment: Screen Sharing is an app built into macOS.

Comment: Are both machines on the same network. Or better asked are they using the same speed. Because lower speed means pixelated screen sharing.

Comment: Screen Sharing, the built-in Mac app. And yes both machines are on the same network connected. MacBook with 802.11ac, the Mini with a cat5e cable.

Comment: Best guess is that the remote screen isn’t retina, and the guest doesn’t know how to upscale it.